# Phase margin Vs damping ratio: Intutive explanation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control, passive-networks, stability

While designing the compensator for SMPS we always talk about the relation between phase margin and damping factor( or Quality factor).

I don't completely understand how damping plays such a keyrole in determining phase margin?

Even in a simple RLC circuit the phase difference between input and output is attributed due to all the components, not just resistor alone.
Also in most of the graphs the relation between phase margin and damping factor is only shown for phase margins in the range of 0 deg to 90 deg. What happens to phase margin higher than that?

[image]

Comment: You can have a look at a seminar taught at APEC (https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf) (p 95) which details the relationship between the open-loop phase margin and the closed-loop quality factor of a switching converter. It is a convenient way to look at a power supply loop gain in the vicinity of crossover and *approximate* the shape to that of a 2nd-order system without zeroes. Going through the maths, it becomes possible to link the phase margin (design criteria) to the transient response you will obtain in closed loop (design goal).

Comment: *"we always talk about the relation between phase margin and damping factor"*. Can't recall that one - where did you see that or hear that? From my standpoint, if designing the compensator you have to counter the 180 degrees shift brought about by the LC in the SMPS and that "unwanted" 180 deg phase shift occurs whatever the damping ratio (within extreme limits of course).

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-004-systems-modeling-and-control-ii-fall-2007/lecture-notes/lecture32.pdf
Page 8